# YAML unnamed object in list

Tags: python, yaml

I'm using PyYAML 5.4.1 with Python 3.7.3, and I'm having trouble getting the YAML output I'm going for.  I'd like an "unnamed object" in a list (not sure how else to phrase that), like this:

```
- 
  a: 1
  b: 2
```

But I keep getting variations of the following output:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> print(yaml.dump([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]))
- a: 1
  b: 2
```

Oddly enough when I go the other way, I get the same results using two different inputs:

```
>>> x = '''
... -
...   a: 1
...   b: 2
... '''
>>> print(yaml.load(x, Loader=yaml.Loader))
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]

>>> y = '''
... - a: 1
...   b: 2
... '''
>>> 
>>> print(yaml.load(y, Loader=yaml.Loader))
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Comment: `yaml.load` accepts either because it's just a difference in formatting. There's no semantic difference between the two, and I'm not aware of an option to make `yaml.dump` produce the extra blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML allows *compact in-line notation* in block sequence items. That is to say, if your sequence item contains a mapping like this

```yaml
- 
  a: 1
  b: 2
```

you may start the mapping directly on the line with the sequence item indicator:

```yaml
- a: 1
  b: 2
```

The compact notation strips away the header line of the mapping, which could contain an anchor and/or tag for the mapping, e.g.

```yaml
- &a !!map
  a: 1
  b: 2
```

Since you are not using those features, the compact in-line notation is perfectly valid and, as you discovered yourself, has the same semantics as the non-compact notation with an empty header on the sequence indicator's line.

Compare this to the fact that you cannot emit comments, but input with comments still loads the same data as input without comments does. Your issue is exactly that, just with whitespace instead of comments. PyYAML does not provide an option to modify this behavior, so you cannot use it to produce the exact output you want, but this should not matter since you *are* able to produce equivalent output. If, for some reason, you require complete control over the output, YAML is the wrong tool for you and you need to use something like XML that does define a complete model of its lexical structure and therefore allows you to tightly control whitespace in the output.

By the way, „unnamed object“ is not a term that makes sense in YAML context since there are no „named objects“. YAML's structure is a node graph where a node can be a scalar, a mapping or a sequence. A sequence contains a list of child nodes, a mapping contains a list of key-value pairs where both the key and the value are nodes. In `a: 1`, *a* is not a name, but a scalar node. It is valid YAML to write `[a, b]: 1` which makes it obvious that the key is not a name, but some kind of node.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response.  I realize the YAML is valid either way, but I was hoping (maybe unnecessarily) for more control over the specific look of the output.